# VBA, How to make formula into Macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have the following basic formula,

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)
```

How can I make this into a macro, so on my selected cell it pastes this formula? Just instead of copying and pasting over and over it may be easier to make this a shortcut to a macro. Also is this something that can be applied among-st any formulas?

Thanks

Comment: if you select all cells that need to contain any data or formula and press F2 for edit, type or past content, and then CTRL+ENTER it will past in all selected cells.

Comment: I was going to say this is easily solved with drag down as well....however a1 would need to be $A$1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub qwerty()
   ActiveCell.Formula = "=LEFT(A1,FIND(""."",A1)-1)"
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

We double-up on the double-quotes!

Answer (score 2):

You can also create custom function:

```
     Function MyLeft(my_Cell_String) As String
         MyLeft = Left(my_Cell_String, InStr(1, my_Cell_String, ".") - 1)
     End Function
```

Then your formula in the cell will be:

```
     =MyLeft(A1)
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this is really good, was looking for this actually.